# Не работает передвижение через нажатие клавиш

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я только начал изучать Unity и делал по гайду. Все в порядке: в консоле нет ошибок. Но при нажатии клавиши ничего не происходит.

Вот код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class SphereMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float runSpeed = 500f;
    public float jumpForce = 15f;
    public float strafeSpeed = 500f;

    protected bool strafeLeft=false;
    protected bool strafeRight=false;
    protected bool doJump =false;



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            strafeLeft = true;

        }   else
        {
            strafeLeft = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            strafeRight = true;

        }  else
        {
            strafeRight = false;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            doJump = true;
        }    

          
       

    }
    void FixeUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну так у вас движение эта строка: `rb.AddForce(0, 0, runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);`, тут никак не используются ваши `strafeLeft`, `strafeRight` и `doJump`, с чего бы ему реагировать на нажатия

Comment: тогда что мне нужно сделать что бы он задвигался?я попробовал поставить что то другое результат таков же

Comment: я, к сожалению или к счастью, не Unity разработчик, по-этому, я просто указал вам причину отсутствия ожидаемого вами поведения